# V-Modell-XT Projektassistent: HTML export fails with JooConverter exception: OpenOfficeException / SocketException: connection reset

Tags: project-management

(Projektassistent v1.4 / installed with `V-Modell-XT-1.4-online-installer.jar`) exporting a project model to HTML causes this logoutput or more specific the last error message:

```
2013-12-18 11:23:37,009 [Thread-5] ERROR com.foursoft.fourever.export - Exception caught from V-Modell exporter.
de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.steuerung.exception.ExportException: Unerwarteter Fehler im JooConverter (OpenOffice)!
   net.sf.jooreports.openoffice.connection.OpenOfficeException: conversion failed; com.sun.star.lang.DisposedException: java.io.IOException: com.sun.star.io.IOException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.steuerung.handler.JooConverterHandler.convert(JooConverterHandler.java:99)
    ...
    at com.foursoft.projektassistent.view.util.SwingWorkerVariant$2.run(SwingWorkerVariant.java:66)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2013-12-18 11:23:37,010 [Thread-5] ERROR com.foursoft.projektassistent.projekt - Error while exporting.
com.foursoft.fourever.export.exception.ExportException: Unerwarteter Fehler im JooConverter (OpenOffice)!
   net.sf.jooreports.openoffice.connection.OpenOfficeException: conversion failed; com.sun.star.lang.DisposedException: java.io.IOException: com.sun.star.io.IOException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at edu.tum.cs.vmodell.export.impl.VModellExporterImpl.export(VModellExporterImpl.java:179)
    at com.foursoft.fourever.vmodell.exporter.ExporterBackupFacade.export(ExporterBackupFacade.java:59)
    at com.foursoft.fourever.vmodell.exporter.ExporterMergeFacade.export(ExporterMergeFacade.java:77)
    at com.foursoft.projektassistent.projekt.impl.VMProjektManagerImpl.exportVModel(VMProjektManagerImpl.java:2540)
    at com.foursoft.projektassistent.view.impl.TailorView$1.doNonUILogic(TailorView.java:254)
    at com.foursoft.projektassistent.view.util.SwingWorkerVariant.construct(SwingWorkerVariant.java:108)
    at com.foursoft.projektassistent.view.util.SwingWorkerVariant$2.run(SwingWorkerVariant.java:66)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.steuerung.exception.ExportException: Unerwarteter Fehler im JooConverter (OpenOffice)!
   net.sf.jooreports.openoffice.connection.OpenOfficeException: conversion failed; com.sun.star.lang.DisposedException: java.io.IOException: com.sun.star.io.IOException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.steuerung.handler.JooConverterHandler.convert(JooConverterHandler.java:99)
    at de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.steuerung.handler.HTMLHandler.convert(HTMLHandler.java:98)
    at de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.steuerung.impl.ODTReportGenerator.export(ODTReportGenerator.java:600)
    at edu.tum.cs.vmodell.export.impl.VModellExporterImpl.export(VModellExporterImpl.java:173)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: should be moved to more appropriate site: http://pm.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is not clear, but since the `*.odt` file is nevertheless created in the export dir it can just be openened and one can `Save as ...` HTML file instead as well.

and here some previous log entries that could potentially be useful finding the root cause:

```
2013-12-18 11:22:26,192 [Thread-3] ERROR com.foursoft.fourever.xmlfileio - No complex type Zusatzthema
2013-12-18 11:22:26,192 [Thread-3] ERROR com.foursoft.fourever.xmlfileio - No complex type Zusatzthema
2013-12-18 11:23:00,484 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.TableHandler - Table configuration: Invalid table header cell style!
2013-12-18 11:23:01,765 [Thread-5] WARN  com.foursoft.fourever.openoffice - OpenOffice already running....
2013-12-18 11:23:02,754 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.template.TemplateTransformer - Could not open referenced template "MakeLinkTo": No template found for name "MakeLinkTo"!
2013-12-18 11:23:02,769 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.template.TemplateTransformer - Could not open referenced template "MakeLinkTo": No template found for name "MakeLinkTo"!
2013-12-18 11:23:20,604 [Thread-5] WARN  com.foursoft.fourever.openoffice - OpenOffice already running....
2013-12-18 11:23:20,674 [Thread-5] ERROR com.foursoft.fourever.draw - Draw error occurred.
com.sun.star.lang.DisposedException: java_remote_bridge com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.java_remote_bridge@393ec620 is disposed
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.java_remote_bridge.checkDisposed(java_remote_bridge.java:702)
    ...
    at com.foursoft.projektassistent.view.util.SwingWorkerVariant$2.run(SwingWorkerVariant.java:66)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2013-12-18 11:23:20,680 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.ImageHandler - Could not open image images/PTV_df42106fce7993f.gif!
2013-12-18 11:23:20,690 [Thread-5] WARN  com.foursoft.fourever.openoffice - OpenOffice already running....
2013-12-18 11:23:20,691 [Thread-5] ERROR com.foursoft.fourever.draw - Draw error occurred.
de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.openoffice.exception.OpenOfficeException: OpenOffice document not initialized.
    at de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.openoffice.documents.ODTReportDocument.<init>(ODTReportDocument.java:53)
    ...
    at com.foursoft.projektassistent.view.util.SwingWorkerVariant$2.run(SwingWorkerVariant.java:66)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2013-12-18 11:23:20,703 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet - Could not find a snippet image for the snippet with id set:
2013-12-18 11:23:20,703 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: d46811643407f31-dc2f116434d0752-1393a1164341bca2
2013-12-18 11:23:20,704 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet - Could not find a snippet image for the snippet with id set:
2013-12-18 11:23:20,704 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: d46811643407f31-dc2f116434d0752-1393a1164341bca2
2013-12-18 11:23:20,704 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: d46811643407f31-dc2f116434d0752-6b811643421c56
2013-12-18 11:23:20,704 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet - Could not find a snippet image for the snippet with id set:
2013-12-18 11:23:20,704 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: d46811643407f31-dc2f116434d0752-6b811643421c56
2013-12-18 11:23:20,704 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: d46811643407f31-10a1511759fd9725-16eb911759ff2d84
2013-12-18 11:23:20,704 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet - Could not find a snippet image for the snippet with id set:
2013-12-18 11:23:20,704 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: d46811643407f31-10a1511759fd9725-16eb911759ff2d84
2013-12-18 11:23:20,704 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: d46811643407f31-11af9116435066e8-d32f117c547ee58
2013-12-18 11:23:20,705 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet - Could not find a snippet image for the snippet with id set:
2013-12-18 11:23:20,705 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: d46811643407f31-11af9116435066e8-d32f117c547ee58
2013-12-18 11:23:20,705 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: d46811643407f31-11af9116435066e8-f710117c54823f8
2013-12-18 11:23:20,705 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet - Could not find a snippet image for the snippet with id set:
2013-12-18 11:23:20,705 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: d46811643407f31-11af9116435066e8-d32f117c547ee58
2013-12-18 11:23:20,705 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: d46811643407f31-11af9116435066e8-f710117c54823f8
2013-12-18 11:23:20,706 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet - Could not find a snippet image for the snippet with id set:
2013-12-18 11:23:20,707 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: fb18116435f01eb-19a411643651eae
2013-12-18 11:23:20,707 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: fb18116435f01eb-12e1511643667610
2013-12-18 11:23:20,707 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: fb18116435f01eb-11fa2116436549b5
2013-12-18 11:23:20,707 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet - Could not find a snippet image for the snippet with id set:
2013-12-18 11:23:20,707 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: fb18116435f01eb-11fa2116436549b5
2013-12-18 11:23:20,707 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: fb18116435f01eb-59ca116436809b0
2013-12-18 11:23:20,707 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: fb18116435f01eb-15be1164380d71d-395d116436569c0
2013-12-18 11:23:20,708 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet - Could not find a snippet image for the snippet with id set:
2013-12-18 11:23:20,708 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: fb18116435f01eb-15be1164380d71d-395d116436569c0
2013-12-18 11:23:20,708 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: fb18116435f01eb-15be1164380d71d-1195711a977992e2
2013-12-18 11:23:20,708 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: fb18116435f01eb-15be1164380d71d-1011c11a977d2f81
2013-12-18 11:23:20,708 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: fb18116435f01eb-15be1164380d71d-e45611643658caa
2013-12-18 11:23:20,708 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet - Could not find a snippet image for the snippet with id set:
2013-12-18 11:23:20,708 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: fb18116435f01eb-15be1164380d71d-e45611643658caa
2013-12-18 11:23:20,709 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: fb18116435f01eb-15be1164380d71d-395d116436569c0
2013-12-18 11:23:20,709 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet - Could not find a snippet image for the snippet with id set:
2013-12-18 11:23:20,709 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: fb18116435f01eb-15be1164380d71d-e45611643658caa
2013-12-18 11:23:20,709 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: fb18116435f01eb-d675116437dfb3e
2013-12-18 11:23:20,709 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: fb18116435f01eb-28871164365afd2
2013-12-18 11:23:20,709 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet - Could not find a snippet image for the snippet with id set:
2013-12-18 11:23:20,709 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: fb18116435f01eb-28871164365afd2
2013-12-18 11:23:20,709 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: fb18116435f01eb-11fa2116436549b5
2013-12-18 11:23:20,709 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet - Could not find a snippet image for the snippet with id set:
2013-12-18 11:23:20,710 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: fb18116435f01eb-28871164365afd2
2013-12-18 11:23:20,710 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: fb18116435f01eb-79ac116437f3890
2013-12-18 11:23:20,710 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: fb18116435f01eb-1dd1164365ce47
2013-12-18 11:23:20,710 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet - Could not find a snippet image for the snippet with id set:
2013-12-18 11:23:20,710 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: d46811643407f31-11af9116435066e8-f710117c54823f8
2013-12-18 11:23:20,710 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: d46811643407f31-11af9116435066e8-63ab117c5488b42
2013-12-18 11:23:20,711 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet - Could not find a snippet image for the snippet with id set:
2013-12-18 11:23:20,711 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: 15bc311643601d9c-9e811176339c5eb
2013-12-18 11:23:20,711 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: 15bc311643601d9c-15212117633cecca
2013-12-18 11:23:20,711 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: 15bc311643601d9c-107e0117633ad729
2013-12-18 11:23:20,711 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet - Could not find a snippet image for the snippet with id set:
2013-12-18 11:23:20,711 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: 15bc311643601d9c-9e811176339c5eb
2013-12-18 11:23:20,711 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: 15bc311643601d9c-15212117633cecca
2013-12-18 11:23:20,711 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: 15bc311643601d9c-a291117633bff32-395d116436569c0
2013-12-18 11:23:20,711 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet - Could not find a snippet image for the snippet with id set:
2013-12-18 11:23:20,711 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: 15bc311643601d9c-107e0117633ad729
2013-12-18 11:23:20,711 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: 15bc311643601d9c-e3e117633f85dd
2013-12-18 11:23:20,711 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: 15bc311643601d9c-161e9117634165fd
2013-12-18 11:23:20,711 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: 15bc311643601d9c-11121117633b3993
2013-12-18 11:23:20,712 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet - Could not find a snippet image for the snippet with id set:
2013-12-18 11:23:20,712 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: 15bc311643601d9c-a291117633bff32-395d116436569c0
2013-12-18 11:23:20,712 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: 15bc311643601d9c-a291117633bff32-1195711a977992e2
2013-12-18 11:23:20,712 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: 15bc311643601d9c-a291117633bff32-1011c11a977d2f81
2013-12-18 11:23:20,712 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: 15bc311643601d9c-a291117633bff32-e45611643658caa
2013-12-18 11:23:20,713 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet - Could not find a snippet image for the snippet with id set:
2013-12-18 11:23:20,713 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: 15bc311643601d9c-a291117633bff32-e45611643658caa
2013-12-18 11:23:20,713 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: 15bc311643601d9c-a291117633bff32-395d116436569c0
2013-12-18 11:23:20,713 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet - Could not find a snippet image for the snippet with id set:
2013-12-18 11:23:20,713 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: 15bc311643601d9c-a291117633bff32-e45611643658caa
2013-12-18 11:23:20,713 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: 15bc311643601d9c-161e9117634165fd
2013-12-18 11:23:20,713 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: 15bc311643601d9c-11121117633b3993
2013-12-18 11:23:20,714 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet - Could not find a snippet image for the snippet with id set:
2013-12-18 11:23:20,714 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: 15bc311643601d9c-11121117633b3993
2013-12-18 11:23:20,714 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: 15bc311643601d9c-9e811176339c5eb
2013-12-18 11:23:20,714 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet - Could not find a snippet image for the snippet with id set:
2013-12-18 11:23:20,714 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: 15bc311643601d9c-11121117633b3993
2013-12-18 11:23:20,714 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: 15bc311643601d9c-e9061176344244b
2013-12-18 11:23:20,714 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: 15bc311643601d9c-e4a5117633b8bb8
2013-12-18 11:23:20,714 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet - Could not find a snippet image for the snippet with id set:
2013-12-18 11:23:20,714 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: d46811643407f31-11af9116435066e8-f710117c54823f8
2013-12-18 11:23:20,714 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: d46811643407f31-11af9116435066e8-63ab117c5488b42
2013-12-18 11:23:20,714 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet - Could not find a snippet image for the snippet with id set:
2013-12-18 11:23:20,714 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: d46811643407f31-11af9116435066e8-63ab117c5488b42
2013-12-18 11:23:20,714 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: d46811643407f31-11af9116435066e8-d32f117c547ee58
2013-12-18 11:23:20,714 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet - Could not find a snippet image for the snippet with id set:
2013-12-18 11:23:20,714 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: d46811643407f31-11af9116435066e8-63ab117c5488b42
2013-12-18 11:23:20,714 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: d46811643407f31-10a1511759fd9725-16eb911759ff2d84
2013-12-18 11:23:20,715 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet - Could not find a snippet image for the snippet with id set:
2013-12-18 11:23:20,715 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: d46811643407f31-11af9116435066e8-63ab117c5488b42
2013-12-18 11:23:20,715 [Thread-5] WARN  de.tuc.in.sse.weit.export.ootrans.transform.snippets.impl.Snippet -  Id: d46811643407f31-1c1a116435138ce-13cc01196fc504a7
```